# What is the efficient way of parsing string on embedded system?

Tags: c, string, parsing, embedded, avr

I'm new to this whole embedded thinking about memory etc.  I wonder wheter ther is the most efficient way of parsing the strings of known structure, but unknown length on embedded system. (some approaches every embedded developer should know are welcome).

I have structures like the one bold below coming to my avr. Those are basicly commands determining certain actions to be performed by my avr. I don´t want to use a String-class, because of reasons.

**number delimiter string delimiter string**

I don´t have any power over the protocol. I have a solution using a function with `strtok()`, `strcpy()` in it.  I fill the array with the tokens an then i have some if/else if conditions to perform actions.

But I wonder if there is a solution like state machine (reading character by character) or similiar which works more efficient on embedded systems. I searched for quite a time now and i would be thankful to receive any hints on this fairly common promblem of string parsing.

Thx for the input. I´m not asking for a solution, but for an approach.

Comment: "because of reasons"? That doesn't really help understand why you don't want to use a string class

Comment: @TomTanner I think the OP is a politician :)

Comment: If you really mean to ask for solution rather than approach, I'll vote to close this question.

Comment: Use the string functions, they are simple and won't cause a lot of overhead. Otherwise parsing with a simple state machine seems also a good aproach as the format you want to parse looks pretty simple. Maybe you want to modify your question and include some sample of command strings.

Comment: I´m very low on memory and String class isn´t that memory friendly in my experience. That´s the main reason. On the other hand the methods are really cool.  @user3528438 I already have a working solution, but i think there are obvious things, that i don´t know about yet.

Comment: @TomTanner low on memory and i'm greedy on my memory =)

Comment: C has no classes. The string library, however should be pretty compact if you only link the functions actually used.

Answer (score 2):

A simple while loop with an array of buffers would save some of the processing, along the following lines (no error checking here or anything)

```
 pos = 0;
 while (c = get_next_char(), c != delim) { buff[BUFF_N][pos++] = c; }
 buff[BUFF_N][pos] = 0;

 pos = 0;
 while (c = get_next_char(), c != delim) { buff[BUFF_S1][pos++] = c; }
 buff[BUFF_S1][pos] = 0;

 pos = 0;
 while (c = get_next_char(), c != '\n') { buff[BUFF_S2][pos++] = c; }
 buff[BUFF_S2][pos] = 0;
```

which would be moderately more efficient that using strtok and strcpy as you're reading the characters into the right place.

Comment: My paranoia says there should be an overflow/reset counter on the `while` loops, eg `{` … ` if (pos > INSANE_LENGTH) { return ERROR; } }` or so?

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with automatically just using strtok for embedded system, since it modifies the first argument (large strings can often be read only).  It is fairly simple to use `strchr()`, strspn() or `strcspn()` to accomplish the same objectives and you can control whether you modify the original string and use a pointer or `strncpy()` and null terminate it to write-able memory.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to parse something non-trivial, take a look at [flex](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/) and [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/index.html).

There is quite a steep learning curve but it has two big advantages over other approaches.

1. It can be made to deal very well with miss-formed text and provides where other approaches will result in a crash or security problem.
2. It makes no use of external libraries so only the actual generated parsing code is used.

Answer (score 0):

I think strtok() should be enough. Depending on how constrained your hardware is you should avoid strcpy() as you will end up holding the string twice in memory.

Use strtok() to locate your strings then assign the address to a pointer, for later use. That way you have the original string however long it may be plus three or four pointers which would consume a fixed 12/16 bytes.